# How to implement a background service that will run when the app is closed and stop when the app is open

Tags: android, android-service

How to implement a background service that will run when the app is closed and stop when the app is open.I have a singleton websocket connection if app is closed i should be able to notify the user via notification if app is open then i should be able to update ui from single websocket communication.

Answer (score 0):

onStop() of your MainActivity you can start the service, in onCreate() you can check if service is running, if it is running you can stop it.

```
  public static boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass, Context context) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method will tell you weather service is running or not